# Upload app in playstore , but my app not show in some device?

Tags: android, upload

I have uploaded an app in the playstore , but my app is not showing in some device under kitkat version? how setting filter search in my app

How can I set the filter for my app so that it is visible for all devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use minimum sdk version to work on every device

Comment: thanks for your answer bro, sorry to late accept :)